# set build.xml <exec> failure value

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to read the "Application.revision" property from a application.properties file into a variable called "svna.version" before my buildscript tries to set a variable.  On some of my systems I don't have a svn client so svnversion fails and it goes blank.  instead of failing, I want it to be the last known value.

How do I set svna.version?  I'm trying to do something like this

```
    <propertyfile file="src/CASUAL/resources/CASUALApp.properties"/>
    <property name="svna.version" value="${Application.revision}"/>
```

I just need to know how to read a property into an Ant variable.  the value is not read from the properties file in the example above.  it's read as a literal string.

As requested I am adding in the contents of my properties file:

```
Application.name=CASUAL
Application.title=CASUAL R
Application.version=${Application.revision}.${Application.buildnumber}
Application.vendor=AdamOutler
Application.homepage=xda-developers.com
Application.description=CASUAL Cross-platform ADB Scripting Universal Android Loader
Application.vendorId=AdamOutler
Application.id=${Application.name}
Application.lookAndFeel=system
Application.buildnumber=2,888
Application.revision=254
```

I need to read the Application.revision into the Property "svna.version" but it's reading as a literal string instead of a key-value pair.

Comment: Can you include the contents of your properties please?

Comment: Included the information you're after.  I'm just trying to figure out how to get set build.xml Property "svna.version" as the Application.revision value which is currently "254"

Comment: If you get the String literal it means that the variable doesn't exist.

Comment: nope, it exists.  I was just loading it wrong.  thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok - just spotted it.  You need to use `<loadproperties/>` or `<property file="foo.properties"/>` The task you're using is for writing properties files not loading them.

Loading properties [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadproperties.html) or indeed [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html)

Writing properties [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/propertyfile.html)

Running ant with -d and -v are very helpful here.

Comment: ok. so first I run <exec outputproperty="svna.version" executable="svnversion" failifexecutionfails="false" >. then I run <loadproperties srcfile="src/CASUAL/resources/CASUALApp.properties"/>  this makes it so if the svnversion command fails, then it pulls from the properties file.   awesome! thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add this finished code sample which attempts to load svnversion from the command, and if it fails, it loads from the stored variable.

```
   <target name="-pre-init" description="Sets the buildversion for the current build">
        <exec outputproperty="svna.version" executable="svnversion" failifexecutionfails="false" >
            <arg value="-c" />
            <redirector>
                <outputfilterchain>
                    <tokenfilter>
                        <replaceregex pattern="^[0-9]*:?" replace="" flags="g"/>
                        <replaceregex pattern="M" replace="" flags="g"/>
                    </tokenfilter>
                </outputfilterchain>
            </redirector>
        </exec> 
        <echo>revision after svnversion command: ${svna.version}</echo>

        <loadproperties srcfile="src/CASUAL/resources/CASUALApp.properties"/>
        <property name="svna.version" value="${Application.revision}"/>
        <echo>Loaded property value: ${svna.version}</echo>
        <echo>revision after loaded property: ${svna.version}</echo>
```